Incorrect lamports calulaction
I'm new to Solana development, I want to get my wallet balance, which is 5 sol. When I do
    client = AsyncClient("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
    res = await client.get_balance(my_address)
    v = res.value / 1_000_000_000
    print(v)

It shows 15.000000012 Sol. Block explorer shows 5 Sol. Please help.

Helps to see the key since it's just devnet. Most likely, you passed a different key.

one reason could probably be your checking your balance on main net in your explorer. You could try changing your network in your explorer and see what happens
